# Firebase InAppMessaging fail to load a test message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Try to show InAppMessaging in ios apps.
What i've doneL import firebase, firbaseapp.configure

Error shown after re-build the apps

[image]

Comment: Well, that looks like a configuration issue within your code so that's a good place to start looking for issues. Without more data and debugging details, there's not much else we can do. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have already awaited upon *Firebase.initializeApp()*.